# Error in filter(x, PHETAS[[i]], sides = 1) : missing values in 'filter' using Sieve Bootstrap Based Test with Mann-Kendall for Trend Analysis

Tags: r, testing, trend

I applied the Mann-Kendall test with autocorrelation enhancement as stated on this website:     https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/funtimes/vignettes/trendtests.html

The given code worked for a simple dataframe with a time series from 2007 to 2022. I tried the same for another dataframe. Even after creating it on my own, I get the error  `Error in filter(x, PHETAS[[i]], sides = 1) : missing values in 'filter'`. And I honestly have no idea how to fix it.

Its from the funtimes library

```
Refenu_summary_byyearoC <- data.frame(
  year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019),
  Total_Enucleation = c(748, 762, 817, 844, 891, 940, 911, 970)
)
```

```
apply(Refenu_summary_byyearoC["Total_Enucleation"], 2, function(x) {
  notrend_test(x, B = 1000, test = c("MK"),
               ar.method = "HVK", ar.order = NULL,
               factor.length = c("user.defined", "adaptive.selection"),
               Window = NULL, q = 3/4, j = c(8:11))$p.value
})
```

In my opinion there is a downward trend of my data and I want to display it with a p-value using the mann-kendall test. I could just use the mann-kendall test and be happy with the p-value and tau, but I was advised to consider the bootstrap to avoid false results because of autocorrelation of my time series.

Comment: So what does `traceback()` tell you? I’m guessing that we might get an error related to a missing function. Only a guess based on never having seen the `notrendtest` function before.

Comment: 6.stop("missing values in 'filter'")
5.filter(x, PHETAS[[i]], sides = 1)
4.ARest(x, ar.order = ar.order, ar.method = ar.method, ic = ic)
3.notrend_test(x, B = 1000, test = c("MK"), ar.method = "HVK",
ar.order = NULL, factor.length = c("user.defined", "adaptive.selection"),
Window = NULL, q = 3/4, j = c(8:11))
2.FUN(newX[, i], ...)
1.apply(Refenu_summary_byyearoC["Total_Enucleation"], 2, function(x) {
notrend_test(x, B = 1000, test = c("MK"), ar.method = "HVK",
ar.order = NULL, factor.length = c("user.defined", "adaptive.selection"),
Window = NULL, q = 3/4, j = c(8:11))$p.value ...

Comment: I think I found a solution. ar.order = Null needs to be changed according to "order of the autoregressive model when ic = "none", or the maximal order for IC-based filtering. Default is round(10*log10(length(x))), where x is the time series" So based on your data choose a number for your autoregressive model and you are good to go.